# JAVA - Getting a Date from JDatePicker - class java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to class java.util.Date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I'm building a very simple expense tracker:

```
public class ExpenseTracker {

JFrame frame;
JPanel mainPanel;
JPanel inputPanel;
JPanel registerPanel;
DefaultTableModel tableModel;
JDatePicker datePicker;
JTextField nameTextField;
JTextField amountTextField;
SimpleDateFormat sdf;
Date date;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ExpenseTracker().buildGUI();
}

public void buildGUI() {

    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel = new JPanel();
    inputPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(inputPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    
    JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name: ");
    nameLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 25));
    nameTextField = new JTextField();
    nameTextField.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(10));
    JLabel dateLabel = new JLabel("Date: ");
    dateLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 25));
    datePicker = new JDatePicker();


    JLabel amountLabel = new JLabel("Amount: ");
    amountLabel.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 25));
    amountTextField = new JTextField();
    amountTextField.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(5));

    
    JButton addExpense = new JButton("Add");
    addExpense.addActionListener(new addExpenseListener());

    inputPanel.add(nameLabel);
    inputPanel.add(nameTextField);
    inputPanel.add(dateLabel);
    inputPanel.add(datePicker);
    inputPanel.add(amountLabel);
    inputPanel.add(amountTextField);
    inputPanel.add(addExpense);
    
    
    registerPanel = new JPanel();
    tableModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    JTable register = new JTable(tableModel);
    tableModel.addColumn("Name");
    tableModel.addColumn("Date");
    tableModel.addColumn("Amount");
    register.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    registerPanel.add(register);
    
    
    
    mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.NORTH, inputPanel);
    mainPanel.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, registerPanel);
    frame.add(mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
}


public void addToRegister() {
    String name = nameTextField.getText();
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat();
    Date dateToFormat = (Date) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
    String date = sdf.format(dateToFormat);
    String amount = amountTextField.getText();
    tableModel.addRow(new Object[] {name, date, amount});
}
```

Leaving out a bit of code.
I get the exception:

> class java.util.GregorianCalendar cannot be cast to class
> java.util.Date (java.util.GregorianCalendar and java.util.Date are in
> module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

and I don't know how do I change this. I know the thing is how to get the date from the DatePicker and the class clash there. Using jdatepicker libraries.

Comment: I strongly recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead find a date picker component that supports [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). There are some out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html).

First, make the following change (check [`Calendar#getTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getTime--) to learn more)

```
Date dateToFormat = datePicker.getModel().getValue().getTime();
```

and then switch to `java.time` API as follows:

```
Instant instant = dateToFormat.toInstant();
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());

// A sample formatting
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ENGLISH);
String formattedDateStr = zdt.format(formatter);
```

Now, you can use `formattedDateStr` in your components.

An alternative way to get `ZonedDateTime` can be as [suggested by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74813718/java-getting-a-date-from-jdatepicker-class-java-util-gregoriancalendar-canno/74814074#comment132039665_74814074):

```
GregorianCalendar selected = (GregorianCalendar) datePicker.getModel().getValue();
ZonedDateTime zdt = selected.toZonedDateTime();
```

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

Comment: Thanks, @OleV.V. for the valuable suggestion. I have incorporated it in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! In this method you proposed with getTime() I get the error "The method getTime() is undefined for the type capture#2-of ?". I solved it using a GregorianCalendar object, transforming it to ZonedDateTime and then formatting it with a DateTimeFormatter.